# Everyday German: Asking for a bus-ticket

Tags: preposition, place-name

> **This question also has an answer here (in German):**
>   *[Präpositionen bei Städten, Regionen, Ländern, Staaten und Inseln](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/31120)*

I have to ask for a bus-ticket to the place I work. So I always say to the bus driver:

> Einmal bis zu Tübingen bitte

Is this right or should I use *nach* instead?

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but if you ask that every day, and while it may be good practice... just buy a monthly ticket and save a lot of cash :D

Comment: haha es lohnt sich nicht!! :-D

Comment: Living 50km away from [Tübingen](https://youtu.be/5xBSrqpiiCk), I would suggest to use _Schwäbisch_: "**Oimal nach Tübinga**".

Comment: You can also use the polite way and say: > Ich möchte einen Fahrschein nach Tübingen lösen.

Comment: @Snickbrack: Das würde nicht als höflich, sondern als gestelzt aufgefasst werden, beliebt mir zu vermuten. "Einmal Tübingen" oder nur "Tübingen" dürfte eine häufige Ausdrucksweise sein, "Einmal Tübingen, bitte" oder "Tübingen bitte" als höfliche Variante.

Answer (score 26):

No, this isn't right.

> Einmal nach Tübingen, bitte.

would be fine. You can think of it as a short form of

> Einen Fahrschein für die Fahrt nach Tübingen, bitte.

But you could also say

> Einmal bis Tübingen, bitte.

which would be short for

> Bitte ein Ticket, das bis Tübingen gültig ist.

Comment: Uhm... how do you know that "Einmal bis Tübingen" is short for your last example? Could be plenty of other things and to me, the version you gave is not the most likely one.

Comment: @Emanuel I meant it is a mnemonic or a way of how to make sense of it. I'm sure there would be alternative phrasings, but I'd expect them to be essentially equivalent. If you have a counter example: I'm curious.

Comment: Since it’s Germany, a „Tübingen“ without any extra words is likely the most commonly used phrase. Together with having the exact required amount of money ready, it might be even regarded as being polite…

Comment: @Emanuel - you're probably standing in the bus, talking to the driver. He's going to understand the short-form request ;-) There is virtually no room for misunderstanding here.

Comment: I would just say "Einmal Tübingen bitte". Or "Einmal Tübingen und zurück" if you want a return. You don't need to add extra words, the ticket seller is in a hurry and so are you, and you may not understand each other 100%.

Answer (score 20):

*Zu* cannot be used with towns and cities. It can only be used with

- buildings

  > **Zum** Rathaus
  >   **Zum** Hauptbahnhof
- squares and streets

  > **Zum** Berliner Platz
  >   **Zur** Friedrich-Wilhelm-Straße

To reference countries, towns, even boroughs or suburbs — in short, any political entity — you need to use *nach*

> **Nach** Tübingen
>   **Nach** Berlin-Spandau
>   **Nach** Dänemark
>   **Nach** Bayern
>   **Nach** Skandinavien

And finally, in the case of geographic entities — and some countries — you would need to use *in*:

> **In** den Harz
>   **In** die Mongolei.

No matter which preposition the location requires, adding a *bis* before it, is okay, but usually not required.

> Einmal *nach* Tübingen bitte.
>   Einmal *bis nach* Tübingen bitte.

And, fun fact: if you use a *bis*, the *nach* isn’t required any more, either.

> Einmal *bis* Tübingen bitte.

Whether one prefers *einmal **nach** Tübingen* or *einmal **bis** Tübingen* is personal style. I prefer *nach*, others will choose *bis*.

Comment: Naja, richtig, aber zu 80% am Thema vorbei...

Comment: @Robert ‘Is this right, or should I use *zu* instead?’ ‘*Zu* cannot be used with towns and cities’ – alles weitere ist Erklärung und Erläuterung *warum zu* mit Städten nicht geht.

Comment: Ja, schon richtig, aber es geht um eine Busfahrkarte. (In die Mongolei?)

Comment: @Robert Nuja, wenn es *nur* um Busfahrkarten geht, wäre die Antwort meines Erachtens zu eng gestrickt – vielleicht will er irgendwann einen Flug wo auch immer hin buchen … und aus Russland und China fahren durchaus Busse in die Mongolei (wobei da wahrscheinlich an Bord leider kein Deutsch gesprochen wird ;) ).

Comment: Schon ok... ich sag ja nur, dass ich die Antwort zu ausführlich finde, aber schlecht im Sinne von Abwertung ist sie nicht. :-)

Answer (score 6):

Most common, the others sound weird:

> Einmal bis Tübingen, bitte.

Comment: I disagree. »Einmal nach Tübigen« is at least as common. None of the options that aren’t wrong really sound weird.

Answer (score 5):

You could also use (very common in Austria)

> Nach Tübingen, bitte