# Driving to X: "zu X" or "nach X"?

Tags: grammar, preposition

I hear it everyday in the bus I travel

> Dieser Bus fahrt ab Roßmarkt **zum** Hainig.
>   Dieser Bus fahrt ab Roßmarkt **nach** Grafenrheinfeld.

Why are two different prepositions used in the sentence which means the same?

On what basis should I choose between *nach* and *zu*?

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8479/richtungen-und-ziele-wir-fahren-nach-in-zu-an-artikel-xyz

Comment: @CarstenS: that was something really perfect for what i was looking for.. thanks for the link.

Comment: To the close voter: no duplicate b/c of different language: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/14/if-the-same-question-is-asked-in-german-and-english-is-it-a-duplicate

Comment: Also related: http://german.stackexchange.com/q/23860/15318

Comment: I’ll admit that it can get really confusing: The Munich underground line U6 stops at a station labelled *Harras* and one labelled *Großhadern*. Naively by looking at the underground map, one would assume both to be boroughs of Munich but only Großhadern is one; *Harras* is actually a square — and to make matters worse it comes with an article (and usually also with *an* so *am Harras*). So the underground goes *nach Großhadern* but *zum Harras*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Very rough rule, I'm sure there are some exception:

**Nach** is used for villages, towns, cities and other forms of named human settlements.

> Wir fahren nach Wien.

**Zum/Zur/Zu den** + is used for all other named places.

> Wir fahren zur Donau. (a river)
>   Wir fahren zum Ötscher. (a mountain)
>   Wir fahren zum Stephansplatz. (a square in a city)
>   Wir fahren zum Heumarkt. (a place that takes its name from a market that used to be there)

Comment: So i should suppose `Hainig` is also some sort of other named place. Is it the same with the usage of `ab Roßmarkt` as well?

Comment: @Vini [Haining](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nordwestlicher_Stadtteil_(Schweinfurt)#Hainig) is an industrial estate, so yes, "other named place" fits.

Comment: @stephie: I did not know what was Hainig. For me they are all bus stations :). But thanks for the link.