# Präpositionen bei Städten, Regionen, Ländern, Staaten und Inseln

Tags: preposition, place-name

> **Diese Frage wurde auch hier (auf Englisch) beantwortet:**
>   *[Everyday German: Asking for a bus-ticket](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/23860)*

Wie kann man erschließen, welche Präpositionen bei Städten, Regionen, Ländern, Staaten und Inseln benutzt werden müssen?

Z. B.:

> nach Griechenland fliegen
>   in die Türkei fliegen
>   auf die Kanarischen Inseln fliegen
>   u.s.w.

Comment: Related: [Is there a rule which preposition to use for a place?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/2540/9551) and [Using “nach” or “zu” for landmarks and similar](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/17671/9551)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Generell ist die Bestimmung der Präposition abhängig von dem Geschlecht (falls vorhanden) des Landes/Staats oder der Region/Stadt/Insel. Die meisten Städte (und Länder) stehen ohne Artikel, daher "fliegst du meist NACH Berlin/England". Allerdings gibt es auch hier Ausnahmen, bei denen du eine andere Präposition brauchst. Beispiele sind unten vorhanden.

> Städte:
>   
>   Regulär haben Städte keine Artikel.

- Frankfurt
- New York City
- London
- Lisabon
- Milan
- Singapur

*Hier sollte generell die Präposition "nach..." verwendet werden*

---

> Länder:

**Feminin (sgl.) oder Plural (pl.)**

- Die Türkei (sgl.)
- Die Vereinigten Staaten (pl.)
- Die Schweiz (sgl.)

*Hier sollte generell die Präposition "in (die)..." verwendet werden*

**Maskulin**

- Der Iran
- Der Jemen

*Hier sollte generell die Präposition "in den..." verwendet werden*

**Ohne Geschlecht**

- Schweden
- Deutschland
- Großbritannien

*Hier sollte generell die Präposition "nach..." verwendet werden*

---

> Bundesländer:

**Ohne Geschlecht**

- Bayern
- Sachsen
- Thüringen
- Hessen
- Rheinland-Pfalz

*Hier sollte generell die Präposition "nach..." verwendet werden*

***Ausnahme*** hierbei ist "DAS" Saarland. Durch das Anhängen der Silbe "...land" ist "Saarland" neutrum. Ich komme aus "dem" Saarland/Ich fliege "in das/ins" Saarland

---

> Inseln:

**Feminin (sgl.) oder Plural (pl.)**

- Die Malediven (pl.)
- Die Seychellen (pl.)
- Die Kanarischen Inseln (hier bestimmt durch "die" Insel(n)) (pl.)

*Hier sollte generell die Präposition "auf die..." verwendet werden*

**Ohne Geschlecht**

- Korfu
- Mallorca
- Teneriffa

*Hier sollte generell die Präposition "nach..." verwendet werden*

Comment: Bekommt "Vereinigten Staaten" den Artikel "die", weil "Staaten" plural ist?

Comment: @AdInfinitum Richtig, der Staat (sgl.) und die Staaten (pl.). Daher sagt man "die Vereintigen Staaten".

Comment: @DerGoliHerr danke schön. Wenn du deine Liste erweitern willst, gibt es hier diesbezüglich einen guten Artikel: http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-abc-laendernamen-mit-artikel-laendernamen-ohne-artikel-a-327185.html